# ajax doesn't recognize .js files

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have page where you can post comments using a form that includes a `<textarea>` field.  When you submit the form the data is imported into the DB via AJAX and it is printed on screen.

For this I load a .js file in my main `index.php` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax/addComment.js"></script>
```

When I print it on screen I also print a new form under it so you can comment/reply to the new text.

Now, the new form doesn't know the "addComment.js" (because it was printed on screen via another PHP file with ajax).  If I want the new form to be working I need also to print the script again in the ajax file "addComment.php" (  `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax/addComment.js"></script>`)

This is a problem, because now I have a duplicate of the .js file and, when I submit any form I actually submit it twice which causes duplicate data in my DB.

How can I avoid that?

I hope you got me right...It's ain't easy to copy the code to here...

Comment: Is hard to help without more concrete js code ...

Comment: "I hope you got my right...It's ain't easy to copy the code to here..."  `Copy & Paste` does not work for you?  Just copy your code, paste it in then highlight it all and click the `{}` button to format it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the code ...

I suspect that you need to change the approach to do this staff ,

Remember one thing .. :

```
$('elemnt').click(function()....ajax or whatever)
```

Just will work once your dom is loaded but not when its manipulated after.

So yo need to attach event handlers with on method to a document instead .

```
$(document).on('click','.whatEverelemnt',function()...ajax or whatever)
```

This will work ever , even if the content is loaded by ajax,

hope you help!

Comment: Myster Javi - your answer gave me the right solation. thank you!